# Fastest way to return a html file from middleware

Tags: php, slim

From a cache middleware I use this to return a real html file:

```
$response->getBody()->write( file_get_contents( $filePath ) );
```

Is there a better way ? 
I tried to include a file directly but slim expects a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will be the cleanest, but there is a faster solution:

```
readfile($filepath);
exit;
```

The advantage of `readfile` is that the file doesn't get loaded into memory and will be directly written to the output buffer. Also we do not need to let slim proceed the Response, so we `exit` the script.

You could also do this with fopen and initialize a new `Stream`, that should also not load the file into the memory.

```
$app->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {
    return $response->withBody(new \Slim\Http\Stream(fopen($filePath, 'r')));
});
```

Note: Slim later `echo`s out this output buffer, so this option is not as fast as `readfile`, but still faster as your solution, because it only loads the data 1x in memory. (yours 1x at `file_get_contents` and 1x at the slim response processing)

Comment: Thanks. this looks good. Problem is that my host recommends I don't use 'exit' with their fastcgi setup. is there a way to use your way without exit ?

Comment: @RobertBrax nope